# 419 page expired error when page refreshed after login laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have multiple roles and while logging in it works fine. super admin is directed to admin dashboard and normal user to normal dashboard. but after login if page is refreshed 419 page expired error is shown with route going to login again.
LoginController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Auth;
use App\User;
use App\Roles_Users\Roles_Users;
use App\Roles\Roles;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    //protected $redirectTo = '/';


    public function authenticated($request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        // echo'<pre>';
        // print_r($user);
        // exit;
        $userrole = Roles_Users::where('userid',$user->id)->first();

        if(empty($userrole)){
            return redirect('/welcome');
        }else{
            $role = Roles::where('id',$userrole->roleid)->first();
        }

        if($role->rolename === 'SuperAdmin') {

            $userdata = User::all();
            $data = Roles::all();
            return view('/superadmin.superdash',['userdata'=>$userdata,'data'=>$data]);

        }elseif($role->rolename === 'Admin'){

            return view('/admin.admindash');

        }else{

            return view('/home');
        }

    }

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

//Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'WhoIsUser'], function() {

    Route::resource('roles','Role\RolesController');

    Route::resource('/','Users\UsersController');

    Route::resource('posts','Posts\PostsController');

    Route::resource('userroles','UserRole\UserRolesController');

});
```

Dont know whats going on. May be its my RedirectIfAuthenticated:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was using authenticated of login controller. What i did to solve was create a middleware and send the user roles to a controller and only then redirect according to the roles.
Middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        $userrole = Roles_Users::where('userid',$user->id)->first();

        if(!empty($userrole)){
            $role = Roles::where('id',$userrole->roleid)->first();
        }

        if ($role->rolename === 'SuperAdmin') {

            $request->request->add(['roles' => 'superadmin']); //add request

        } elseif ($role->rolename === 'Admin') {
            $request->request->add(['roles' => 'admin']); //add request

        } else {
            $request->request->add(['roles' => 'normaluser']); //add request

        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Login controller:

```
protected $redirectTo ='/dashboard';
```

Route:

```
Route::get('dashboard', [
    'middleware' => 'assignRole',
    'uses' => 'AdminController@index'
]);
```

Admin Controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if($request['roles'] === 'superadmin') {

            $userdata = User::all();
            $data = Roles::all();
            return view('superadmin.superdash',['userdata'=>$userdata,'data'=>$data]);

        }elseif($request['roles'] === 'admin'){

            return view('admin.admindash');

        }else{

            return view('/home');
        }
    }
```